# creating a new bibtex entry type

Tags: bibtex

I've been using for bibtex for a few years now, and I've finally reached the point where I am fed up with the fact that the "book" entry does not allow for both an editor and an author, and the fact that "translator" is not a valid data entry type (so far as I know).  I regularly work with books that are either editions or translations of medieval manuscriptions, and I'd like to be able to, e.g., do the following:

```
@book{SpWi95,
  year={1995},
  author={Richard Brinkley},
  editor={Spade, Paul Vincent and Gordon A. Wilson},
  title={Richard Brinkley's Obligationes: A Late Fourteenth Century 
Treatise on the Logic of Disputation},
  series={Beitr\"age zur Geschichte der Philosophie und Theologie des 
Mittelalters, neue Folge},
  volume={43},
  address={M\"unster i.\ W.},
  publisher=Aschendorff}
}
```

But I haven't been able to find instructions on how to create a new type of bib entry (called something like "edbook" or maybe "transbook").

Or is there another way that things like this should be handled that I haven't been clever enough to find google in more than a year's worth of searching?

Comment: which style do you use? I suggest biblatex or biblatex-dw. regards

Answer (score 8):

New entry types or extra entry fields won't help unless they are recognized by the bibliography style. So you either need to define a new style or use an existing style that offers the features you want.

In the entry you provided, for example, the bibliography style should output both the `author` and `editor` fields for the entry type `book`. The `achicago` style/package ([manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein/achicago-bst.pdf)) bundled with [`frankenstein`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein) recognizes a number of additional fields for book entries (see below). There may be other `bibtex`-based styles/packages that offer similar features. Alternatively, you could follow Marco's suggestion and make the switch to `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{achicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{spwi95,
  year={1995},
  author={Brinkley, Richard},
  editor={Spade, Paul Vincent and Wilson, Gordon A.},
  title={Richard Brinkley's Obligationes: A Late Fourteenth Century Treatise on the Logic of Disputation},
  series={Beitr\"{a}ge zur Geschichte der Philosophie und Theologie des Mittelalters, neue Folge},
  volume={43},
  address={M\"{u}nster i. W.},
  publisher={Aschendorff},
  flanguage={Language},
  translator={Lastname, Firstname}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{achicago}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]