# Biblatex: Declare new driver with new fields

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

For several reasons I need to declare within a LaTeX-document by help of biblatex a new driver with new fields.

E.g. the following BibTeX-entry may be given:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @aloa{chris,
        fu = {Hawaii},
        fubo = {Hawaiiboooo},
        year = {2015}}
\end{filecontents}
```

Then I'd like to define in the LaTeX-document something like:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{aloa}{%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{fu}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{fubo}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{year}%
    \finentry}
```

And then I'd like to cite the entry in such a way that I get as output in the reference list:

> Hawaii Hawaiiboooo 2015

A minimal example would be like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @aloa{chris,
        fu = {Hawaii},
        fubo = {Hawaiiboooo},
        year = {2015}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{aloa}{%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{fu}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{fubo}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{year}%
    \finentry}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{chris}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do this in the LaTeX-file only (with bibtex and not biber)?

Comment: With Biber this can be done quite easily, see [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) `biblatex`'s user interface does not offer the same for BibTeX though (neither for BibTeX8), so you are will have to resort to hackery. If you insist on not using Biber (why would you), you might be better of with a custom `.bst` file (i.e. dropping `biblatex`), see [creating a new bibtex entry type](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17276/35864).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to create new drivers and new entry fields in `biblatex` even whithout `biber`.

When the backend is not `biber`, `biblatex` uses a special `.bst` file `biblatex.bst` to generate the `.bbl` file, thus one has to modify `biblatex.bst`.  Here is the procedure:

1) locate `biblatex.bst` and make copy of it and rename the copy (i.e., `mybiblatex.bst`) and put the renamed copy somewhere where `bibtex` is able to locate it (a simple solution is to put in the same folder/directory of  the latex file).

2) in the local copy locate `ENTRY` and  add the fields you want to add:

```
ENTRY {
  entryset 
  ...
  fu
  fubo
}
```

this instructs `bibtex`  that `fu` and `fubo` are `bibtex` fields.

3) locate in local copy `FUNCTION {output.fields.3}` and create a new function

```
FUNCTION {output.myfields} {
  "fu"    fu    output:write:field
  "fubo"  fubo  output:write:field
}
```

this function instructs `bibtex` how to treat the new field. for each line the first two arguments are the name of the new field(s); for the third argument, you an use `output:write:<type>`, where `<type>` is one of `name`, `field`, `verb`, `list` or `year`, depending on the datatype of the entry.

4) locate  in the local copy the function `FUNCTION {output:entry}`. Add to this function `output.myfields`, so it should look like

```
FUNCTION {output:entry}{
  ...
  output.fields.3
  output.myfields
  output.compat.1
  ...
}
```

5) for each new driver `<driver>` add  the line

```
FUNCTION {<driver>} { type$ output:entry }
```

in the example, this should be

```
FUNCTION {aloa} {type$ output:entry}
```

6) add the following to your latex source:

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@auxinit@bibtex#1{%
  \blx@auxwrite\blx@auxout@bibtex
    {\def\do##1{,\blx@stripbib{##1}}}
    {\ifx\blx@auxout@bibtex\@mainaux
     \else
       \blx@msg@aux
     \fi
     \string\bibstyle{mybiblatex}\blx@nl
     \string\bibdata{%
       \blx@ctrlfile@bibtex\blxauxsuffix
       \ifx#1\@empty
       \else
         \dolistloop#1%
       \fi}\blx@nl
     \string\citation{biblatex-control}}}
\makeatother
```

this is to tell `bibtex` to use `mybiblatex.bst` instead of the default `biblatex.bst`.

Here is output the on the MWE

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect! Exactly what I wanted...